# card.io linker settings

Tags: ios7, card.io

On the GitHub instructions for Card.io it states "In your project's Build Settings (in the TARGETS section, not the PROJECTS section), add -lc++ to Other Linker Flags."

I can't find an entry of that name in Xcode 5.  Either Im blind or its called something different now. Where should "-lc++" flag now go?

Comment: Cannot find `Other Linker Flags` ? Just type the name in search box and you'll find it.

Answer (score 1):

Its right there in Project > Target > Build Settings. Just type "Other Linker Flags" in the search:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my Xcode 5.0.2 does not have an entry for "Other Linker Flags", but opening the "ScanExample" sample code from GitHub also does not have this entry in my setup.  I found where the sample code has the -lc++ flag in its Linker settings but it is in the entry OTHER_LDFLAGS, so that must be where it goes if your Xcode does not label the Build setting as "Other Linker Flags"

Is this just a setting in my project to show the setting names in a literal style?
If so I'm surprised that using the search field wouldn't find it.

Comment: Looks like it's determined by the Editor menu > Show Setting Names vs. Show Setting Titles.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I knew it must be somewhere.